# Hard drive clone was made without file system

Tags: windows-10, backup

since one of my hard drives lately started to show signs of failing, i yesterday made a clone of that drive using AOMEI Backupper.

The cloning was succesful according to AOMEI, but the drives cannot be accessed through the explorer with the message "drive not ready". (loosely translated from german)

In the disk management the partitions show up without a file system, even though the backup program shows them as NTFS.

Does anyone have an idea, what could cause this or how i can resolve it?
Alternative Backup programs would also be ok.

Comment: There's a lot of drive cloning software around, free and commercial, you could choose the one you like. Clonezilla https://clonezilla.org/ is a nice one in my opinion.

Comment: I had looked up clonezilla, but wanted to try a software that I could run from Windows first, because I needed to use the pc. Please note that the cloned drive was not the system partition and I only accessed files on my system partition while it was backing up the other. If all else fails I will definitely try clonezilla.

Comment: Since this is not a system drive are you really need to mirror it? You could just copy all files to a new one.

Comment: I thought a sector clone would be faster, since it's around 2,5TB of data and Windows copying slows down so much with many small files.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then I would recommend you to try products from EaseUS https://www.easeus.com/download/tbf-download.html or Macrium https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree . I used them both some time ago and they both worked well.

Comment: Macrium was the first program I tried, but it exited with error code 9. In some forum posts u found out that it's probably due to bad or unreadable sectors and a few suggested aomei, which for them worked. I still have an other suggestion from a colleague that I need to try when I get home. I'll update the question or answer it myself when I've tried

Comment: So clonezilla also failed, due to bad sectors on the first partition at about 80%. I will wait, if it also fails for the second partition and then go on and copy the rest from the windows file system. Hopefully the important stuff is still readable

Comment: There's a rescue option in Clonezilla's expert mode which will allow you to copy drive with bad sectors.

Comment: I've now copied the most relevant files to my new drive using windows. Some files from the bad sectors weren't retrievable, but i have the vast majority in a safe place now. The rest is mostly games and applications, which i can just reinstall/redownload if needed.